# How to create smooth paths with a 2D Canvas in HTML?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, canvas, spline

With the help of D3js i am generating splines from a set of points on a 2D canvas in HTML and JavaScript.

```
private spline = d3.line()
  .x(p => p.x)
  .y(p => p.y)
  .curve(d3.curveBundle.beta(1));
```

This is added to a canvas with some native JS code:

```
ctx = [HTMLCanvasElement].getContext('2d'); // pseudo-code

ctx.beginPath();
this.spline(points);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();
```

This works fine in case I am rendering one path at a time. As soon as I am having multiple pathes with the same starting point, they are starting to overlap. And this causes some unwanted rendering effects: These paths are getting edgy and jaggy.

I've already tried to increae the `context.imageSmoothingQuality = 'high'` and played around with `ctx.globalCompositeOperation` without any help.

A possible solution would be IMHO to removed that overlapping part and "glue" the pathes from that point, when they are splitting. The redundant part would be removed and the side effects would be vanished, but this sounds like a hard programming story to figure out reliably where the splines begin.

*Important note:* These splines or pathes are rendered randomly. Only the starting and ending points are fixed. If you like, have a look at: http://b612-webdesign.de/kardion/guilloche/ (Hit "Aktualisieren" to generate a new graph)

[image: pathes rendered in js and html canvas]

**„Minimal“ reproducable example:** https://observablehq.com/@nextlevelshit/d3js-canvas-splines

*You'll find at ObservableHQ an example of my issue. You can change the code and re-run the rendering at anytime.*

Comment: `imageSmoothingQuality` is only for bitmaps (drawImage and pattern), but anyway, even SVG does show it like that, and that"s quite normal: your lines are not overlapping exactly, there will be a tiny fraction of a pixel of difference, which means there will be a a lot of different antialiasing transparency to apply on the same pixels, and accumulating these will render what you see. Even compositing won't help much here: https://jsfiddle.net/se7fjcqv/ Ps: Having a live [MCVE] would probably help a lot helping you.

Comment: @Kaiido I've just added such example.